# Why var variable in javascript become global when used in for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have been told the variable defined by **var** in javascript will be local.

For example:

```
function myFunc(){var v=100; return v;}
```

if you access the v outside the function you will hit

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: v is not defined
```

But then I found when using in for loop, the variable defined by **var** become global. For example

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){/*do nothing*/}
```

After the for loop you can still access the variable i. Why it becomes global? What is the difference when using in function and for loop?

Comment: https://edgecoders.com/function-scopes-and-block-scopes-in-javascript-25bbd7f293d7

Comment: because javascript is "function" scope. Your for loop is still in the global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, `var` is scoped only to the next `function` scope, ignoring all other kinds of blocks (if, for, while, etc.)

You can use `let` instead to solve this, which is scoped to blocks instead. Also look into `const`, which behaves the same as `let`, but can't be reassigned.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let